# How to display text on the view after returning JSON data

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using `ASP.NET MVC 4` and the latest version of `jQuery`.

I have a textbox that is used to enter a branch number. After the branch number is typed in this textbox and looses focus then I need to do an AJAX call to retrieve the branch name. I then need to display this branch name on the view, just for viewing purposes and not to be edited.

My HTML markup for the textbox and "text" for the branch name:

```
<td class="edit-label">Branch Number: <span class="required">*</span></td>
<td>
    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.BranchNumber, new { maxlength = "6" })
    @Html.Display("BranchName", new { id = "BranchName" })
</td>
```

My jQuery code:

```
$('#BranchNumber').blur(function () {
    var url = '@Url.Action("GetBranchName")';
    var data = { branchNumber: $('#BranchNumber').val() };

    $.getJSON(url, data, function (data) {
        $('#BranchName').text(data);  // Need to have an element to populate the data
    });
});
```

My action method that calls a service to bring back the name of the branch:

```
public ActionResult GetBranchName(long branchNumber)
{
    Check.Argument.IsNotNegative(branchNumber, "branchNumber");

    string branchName = myService.GetBranchName(branchNumber);

    return Json(branchName, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

My view model:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public long BranchNumber { get; set; }

    public long BranchName { get; set; }
}
```

When I return the branch name I need to display it on the view.  I'm not sure what is the best way to display it?  I have tried LabelFor and DisplayFor but it is not displaying, so when the branch name is returned then it can't find the control so it is not displayed.  Textbox works fine but I don't want the users to be able to change the name of the branch.

What would be the best solution for this?  Should I just have a span element and then just display the branch name in here?

Comment: you cannot use any **strongly typed** helper for ajax returned value since you will not be able to bind back to razor. So a span is best.

Comment: I wanted to have the it strongly typed so that if the form is refreshed then I need it to keep the branch name there.

Comment: but strongly typed with what? you won't bind from ajax back to your model...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can  use a strongly-typed view, any html element and still allow the model binder do it's job.

```
// your view
// using div as an example
<div id="@("Branch"+Model.BranchName)">@Model.BranchName</div>
//
// in your js do this
$.getJSON(url, data, function (data) {
    $('#Branch'+@Model.BranchName).text(data);
});
```